# What are the advantages of increasing the partition size and decreasing partitions number in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-partitioning

I have 1 master and 3 slaves(4 cores each)

By Default the min partition size in my spark cluster is 32MB and my file size is 41 Gb. 
So i am trying to reduce the number of partitions by changing the minsize to 64Mb

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.setLong("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize", 64*1024*1024)
val data =sc.textFile("/home/ubuntu/BigDataSamples/Posts.xml",800) 
data.partitions.size = 657
```

So what are the advantages of increasing the partition size and reducing the number of partitions. 
Because when my partitions are around 1314 it took around 2-3min appx and even after reducing the partition count, it is still taking same amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

The more partitions the more overhead, but to some extend it helps with performance as you can run all of them in parallel.

So, on one hand it makes sense to keep number of partitions equal to number of cores. On the other it might happen specific partition size lead to specific amount of garbage in the JVM, which might overhead the limit. In this case you'd like to increase number of partitions to reduce memory footprint of each of them.

It might also depend on the workflow. Consider groupByKey vs reduceByKey. In the latter case you can compute a lot locally and send just a little to remote node. Shuffles happen to be written to disk before being sent to remote, thus having more partitions might reduce performance.

It is also true that there is some overhead come along with each partition.

In case you'd like to share cluster with several people, then you might consider approach to take somewhat less number of partitions to process everything, so that all of the users would have some processing time.

Smth like this.